# Php security question

Tags: php, security

Just had a thought

**post.php**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

if (isset($_POST['comment'])) {
insert()
}

<form method="post" action="post.php">

<textarea name="comment"></textarea>

<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit">

</form>

}
```

$_SESSION['id'] needs to be set to access post.php. Is that safe enough?

Just thinking maybe someone can just create a session on their site and make their own post.php and redirect it to my site? can you do that?

```
<form method="post" action="http://mysite.com/post.php">

<textarea name="comment"></textarea>


<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Exucse my limited english

Comment: $_SESSION['id'] is created in the server , it not easy to fake

Comment: @haim evgi: it depends on the session storage system. Some session storage system use cookies to store values.

Comment: @Salaryman so using cookies to store SESSION mean sits not safe enough, right?

Comment: @harshath A Session ID is supposed to be stored in a cookie, as it contains no valuable information and is only used to identify the user. The real valuable information is stored on the server, so no security breach per se.

The question is, how easy is it to guess or steal someone else's Session ID to pose for them and how long is the session valid (what windows does a potential attacker have before the Session ID is worthless).

Answer (score 4):

Just as general advise, I always prefer "bail-out-soon" over "if-if-if". Meaning, the top should look more like :

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    // display_error();
    // redirect()
    // whatever else needs to be done
    exit;
}

// continue as planned
```

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is that people can intercept the packet midflight and rewrite the values of the form to be whatever they want. What security goals are you trying to accomplish? People will always be in complete control over the values sent from the client, make sure your application doesn't assume anything of the data coming back.

Look at Tamper Data for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966

Comment: i don't think it's that critical if people can tamper with the comment they posted themselves (as tamper data would enable them). the issue here is that only logged in people may be able to post. for this, session id hijacking must take place - and that's a different problem.

Comment: @stefan mai: ok, other people rewriting your content by hijacking network traffic may be a problem, but is solved by https.

Answer (score 0):

i can't see any imminent problem. if it's critical, make sure data is sent over https, so people hijacking network traffic can't tamper with it (as Stefan Mai suggested). otherwise, it seems ok - as long as nobody is stealing your users session cookies.

decezes method is just another coding style. it doesn't increase security per se, but may prevent sloppy programmers from making mistakes in the form of:

```
if (checkIfLoggedIn()) {
  doPrivateThing();
}

doAnotherPrivateThing();  // bug: the programmer should have 
                          // put that into the if-conditional
```

otherwise, make sure the session id is stored in a cookie, and never passed transparently over the URL! i'm not sure about the default settings in the php.ini nowadays, but it used to do url rewrites automatically if cookies are disabled. better check that.

as far as i remember, the ini-option is `session.use_only_cookies` (should be enabled)

[php/session security](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.php)

update:

> "Just thinking maybe someone can just create a session on their site"

no, that won't work. sessions are created upon `session_start();` (or sometimes automatically). `$_SESSION['id']` has nothing to do with the `session_id();`, it's just some variable. though it's not very well named, because other could indeed confuse it (maintainability!). better name it `$_SESSION['isUserLoggedIn'];` or something like that.

Comment: Yeah true, security-wise my suggestion doesn't make any difference, if there's no mistake in the code. The point is, a programmer is his own worst enemy, so you always want to reduce the chances of introducing stupid little mistakes that may turn into a security nightmare.

Comment: yes, i wrote exactly that: "may prevent sloppy programmers from making mistakes" :)